# How to disable laptop keyboard/mousepad and stop it from reinstalling itself

Tags: keyboard, device-manager

I'm trying to disable a laptop's internal keyboard and mousepad (Lenovo E50, Windows 10) - when I uninstall them in 'Device Manager' and restart the computer, they reinstall themselves. If I right click on the Device in Device Manager, the option to disable the device is greyed out.

Comment: How about opening up your laptop and unplugging the wire instead ? Would that be a possible solution

Comment: Yeah, just did this in the end :)